# how to change drive letter when using pushd

Tags: windows, batch-file

When we use pushd to change directory to remote server location, it will automatically generates drive letter. If we want to generate specific drive letter, is that possible?

Comment: You could map a drive with `net use`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294761

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cmd - Is it possible to temporarily assign an available drive letter to a local path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482137/cmd-is-it-possible-to-temporarily-assign-an-available-drive-letter-to-a-local)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create MAP Drive by batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294761/how-to-create-map-drive-by-batch-file)